# Required SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have been stuck on this for sometime now.

I have the following SQL Tables:

`department` table

```
Id  Name

 1  DeptA
 2  DeptB
 3  DeptC
```

`users` table

```
 Id   Name  Dept

 101  Alice 2
 102  Bob   3
```

`alpha` table

```
Id   Uid  Title

501  101  HELLO
502  102  HEY
503  101  SQL
```

`beta` table

```
Id   Uid  Title

601  101  HELLO1
602  101  HEY1
603  102  SQL1
```

Explanation:

- There's basically a `users` table which has all the users.
- Each user has a department (`Dept` field)
- Each user has some records, linked to it with `Uid`, in `alpha` and `beta` tables.

The result I want:

```
DeptA DeptB DeptC

  0     4     2
```

I want the count of records in `alpha` and `beta` combined, grouped by `Dept` of the users whose records are there in these tables.

Can someone help me with the SQL query?

Comment: Does the result have to be pivoted into columns, or can you have a row for each department?

Comment: What did you try when getting 'stuck' ?

Comment: Use `UNION ALL` to combine `alpha` and `beta`. Join this with `department` and `users` table, and use `COUNT(*)` and `GROUP BY department.id` to get the total counts.

Comment: The result has to be in columns as the data in rows may be ambiguous.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004603/mysql-pivot-row-into-dynamic-number-of-columns for how to pivot from rows to columns.

Comment: How would it be embiguous if the result were a table with rows `DeptA 0`, `DeptB 4`, and `DeptC 2`?

Comment: [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: Hi @OmGupta Please check my below result. Hope it'll provide your desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your table structure I've used dept id for retrieving result otherwise I used dept name. You can also use COALESCE function if you get NULL

```
-- MySQL
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN d.id = 1 THEN COALESCE(total, 0) END) dept_A
     , SUM(CASE WHEN d.id = 2 THEN COALESCE(total, 0) END) dept_B
     , SUM(CASE WHEN d.id = 3 THEN COALESCE(total, 0) END) dept_C
FROM department d
LEFT JOIN (SELECT u.dept
             , COUNT(1) total
        FROM users u
        INNER JOIN (SELECT uid
                    FROM alpha
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT uid
                    FROM beta) t
                ON u.id = t.uid
        GROUP BY u.dept ) p
        ON d.id = p.dept;
```

Please check url http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/020b2/1